# Recursive on-read highlighting function

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition

I am trying to pass a voice intent to a function that recursively runs until the user says "exit", it. Until the function exits, the function highlights each word in sequence that matches a user's voice intent. My plan is to make a 'cursor' which is a parent node inside a div which structure looks like what I have below:

```
<div> <span id="word"+ i> </span>... </div>
```

each span has a sequential id so that one can easily distinguish them.
My main issue is that I can't figure out how to set my cursor to the next span in the document.

Initially it is set to `window.getSelection()` then I want to select the next span in my div when the user enters an intent that matches the current cursor.innerHtml

currently I get an error saying that 'cursor is undefined' in the console.

```
highlightOnRead=(doc,cursor)=>{
       var transcripts=document.getElementById("transcriptSpan")
        var transcript = transcripts.innerHTML;


              if(transcript !== undefined && transcript!==" "){
              console.log("transcript",transcript)
              console.log("cursor",cursor.anchorNode.parentNode.id) //we only need the word
              console.log("cursor plus 1",cursor.anchorNode.parentNode.nextSibling.id)
              let elem = document.getElementById(cursor.anchorNode.parentNode.id) //the element where the cursor is currently

              if(transcript.includes(" ")){
                transcript = transcript.split(" ").pop()
              }
                if(transcript.toLowerCase() !== elem.innerHTML.toLowerCase() && transcript.toLowerCase() !== 'exit')
                {
                   cursor = cursor.anchorNode.parentNode.nextSibling.id
                  this.props.readAlongHighlight(doc,cursor)
                  console.log(transcript)
                }
                 cursor = cursor.anchorNode.parentNode.nextSibling.id
                  elem.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'; //highlight the span matching the intent
                  //move the cursor to the next element in the div
              this.props.readAlongHighlight(doc,cursor)
              console.log("leaving the function")
              return
            }
            console.log("leaving the function")
          };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out!

```
cursor=document.getElementById(cursor.anchorNode.parentNode.id).nextSibling.nextElementSibling;
```